# How to customize a popup from a toolbar button in Kentico.EMS12.MvcComponents.Widget.RichText

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc

I recently added the nuget packaget for Kentico.EMS12.MvcComponents.Widget.RichText to take advantage of the new froala based widget and inline editor.  This version (based on froala documentation) is very customizable.  Unfortunately the implementation of the nuget package appears to have hidden the base froala library therefore making a big part of the froala documentation not applicable.  I was curious if someone could tell me how I can go about making the calls to customize a toolbar command.  The big issue I had with my initial attempts was I couldn't access the base froala library which means I couldn't make the calls listed in the documentation (for adding a command for example).  I looked at using an event but still didn't seem to be able to get code running in an appropriate context.

Answer (score 0):

The customization of the Rich text widget is a brand new feature and has just been documented here: https://github.com/Kentico/ems-mvc-components/wiki/Implementing-Rich-text-editor-plugins.

Kentico will pass the *FroalaEditor* object as a function parameter into your plugin.
Your plugin can be pushed into the Rich text plugins register. See `plugins.push(myButtonPlugin);`

```js
(function (pageBuilder) {
    var richTextEditor = pageBuilder.richTextEditor = pageBuilder.richTextEditor || {};
    var plugins = richTextEditor.plugins = richTextEditor.plugins || [];

    var sampleButtonPlugin = function (FroalaEditor) {
            FroalaEditor.DefineIcon("sampleButtonIcon", { NAME: "star", SVG_KEY: "help" });
            FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand("sampleButton", {
                title: "Sample Button",
                icon: "sampleButtonIcon",
                callback: function () {
                    // Use the current context to work with the content of the inline editor.
                    console.log(this.html.get());
                }
            });
        };
    plugins.push(myButtonPlugin);
})(window.kentico.pageBuilder);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that I wasn't intending in implementing a plugin in my case.  I can understand why you made that assumption though.  In my case I would like to customize a plugin that you guys wrote.  You have a toolbar button that already exists and has most of what I'd like I just wanted to make a customization to it.  Creating a new plugin may be the way to go but initially sounds like more work than is should be necessary.  As it turns out I believe you guys are actually developing the feature I need.  If you get it out the door quickly enough I might be able to forget this for now.

Comment: I just re-read your answer again.  I realized that the method doesn't expect anything specific in it...just a callback to use.   If I end up proceeding with this type of work I can probably use the above after all